# WPF Keybinding of ALT+0 does not work

Tags: wpf, key-bindings

Does anyone know why keybinding to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> thru <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> does not work in WPF? I even tried it in the WPFApplicationFramework Shortcut Key example and nothing happens if you change the Modifier to the <kbd>ALT</kbd> Key plus NumPad0. It works with Control and NumPad0 though.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind <kbd>alt</kbd> with any of the numberkeys not on the keypad in windows.  The reason you can't is because the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>numpad#</kbd> combination is reserved for inputting most (unicode) characters by code in decimal AFAIK.  e.g., <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0215</kbd> inputs the character "×".  I don't think this could be overridden so you'll have to come up with a different key combination.

Scroll to "Alt + Numpad" in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964658.aspx) or read [this](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) for more information.